# program that determines if array is ascending, descending, or random(C language)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

i have to build a program that scans "size", then array in the size of "size".
returns 1 if ascending, -1 if descending, and 0 if neither.

so for I've came up with this, and its not working.

```
int UpOrDown(int *arr,int size)
{
int i,j,flag;
if(arr[0]<arr[1])// ascending or random
{
    flag=1;
    {
        for(i=1;i<size;i++)
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
                flag=0;
    }
    if (flag=0) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
else //descending or random
{
    flag=-1;
        if(arr[0]>arr[1])  
        {
            for(i=1;i<size;i++)
                if(arr[i]<arr[i+1])
                    flag=0;
        }
        if (flag=0) return 0;
        else return -1;
}
```

i'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: `arr[i+1]` will break the array bounds when `i == size - 1`.

Comment: @Ilia Naleva  It is not clear what to return for example for an array like this { 1, 2, 2 } or { 2, 1, 1 }

Comment: Using your debugger, step through what happens when presented with an empty array and ensure it does nothing, does not crash and return 0. Using your debugger, step through what happens when presented with an array with only one element and ensure it does nothing, does not crash and returns 0.  Using your debugger, step through what happens when presented with an array with two elements that are in ascending order and ensure it does not crash and returns 1. Then test descending order with 2. Then test with 3 with all conditions.  You should then have a good chance at a working prog.

Comment: ...or clear what to return if the array is { 1, 1, 1 }.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some errors:

- Breaking the array bounds
- Incorrect use of `=` instead of `==`

and seems over-complicated. Here is my solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int UpOrDown(int *arr, int size)
// return -1 (falling), 0 (unknown), +1 (rising)
{
    int rising = 0, falling = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[i-1]) {
            rising = 1;
        }
        else if(arr[i] < arr[i-1]) {
            falling = 1;
        }
    }
    return rising - falling;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr1[1] = { 1 };
    int arr2[2] = { 1, 2 };
    int arr3[2] = { 2, 1 };
    int arr4[3] = { 1, 2, 1 };
    int arr5[3] = { 2, 1, 2 };

    printf("%d\n", UpOrDown(arr1, 1));
    printf("%d\n", UpOrDown(arr2, 2));
    printf("%d\n", UpOrDown(arr3, 2));
    printf("%d\n", UpOrDown(arr4, 3));
    printf("%d\n", UpOrDown(arr5, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
0
1
-1
0
0
```

Comment: You might consider an early-out if both `falling` and `rising` are set. Not required, but a simple enough optimization.

Comment: @JimMischel yes I thought of that, but kept the code simple.

Comment: @JimMischel ... because I did not want to overload Ilia Naleva with more than was necessary to solve the "not working" fault.

Answer (score 0):

I find some mistake in your program . please try using 
 if (flag == 0) return 0;
instead of 
 if (flag=0) return 0;

Comment: yes! just noticed that too. i fixed it. its works perfect now. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

For starters in the presented function implementation there is absent the closing brace.

In general the value of the parameter `size` can be equal to `0` or `1`. In this case the function has undefined behavior due to the first statement

```
if(arr[0]<arr[1])
```

Moreover as the parameter has the type int then the user can supply a negative value. So it is better to declare the parameter as having type `size_t`.

Also in the loops like this

```
    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            flag=0;
```

there is an attempt to access beyond the array when the variable `i` is equal to `size - 1`.

In this code snippet that corresponds to the else statement

```
else //descending or random
{
    flag=-1;
        if(arr[0]>arr[1])  
        {
            for(i=1;i<size;i++)
                if(arr[i]<arr[i+1])
                    flag=0;
        }
        if (flag=0) return 0;
        else return -1;
}
```

the function can return -1 even if the array has only two elements that are equal each other.

I can suggest the following function implementation. At least it works.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int UpOrDown(const int a[], size_t n)
{
    int ordered = !(n < 2 || a[0] == a[1]);

    if (ordered)
    {
        ordered = a[0] < a[1];
        size_t i = 2;

        while (i < n && ordered == a[i - 1] < a[i]) i++;

        if (i != n)
        {
            ordered = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ordered = ordered == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    return ordered;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1 };
    int b[] = { 1, 1 };
    int c[] = { 1, 2 };
    int d[] = { 2, 1 };
    int e[] = { 1, 2, 2 };

    printf("a: %d\n", UpOrDown(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)));
    printf("b: %d\n", UpOrDown(b, sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b)));
    printf("c: %d\n", UpOrDown(c, sizeof(c) / sizeof(*c)));
    printf("d: %d\n", UpOrDown(d, sizeof(d) / sizeof(*d)));
    printf("e: %d\n", UpOrDown(e, sizeof(e) / sizeof(*e)));
}
```

The program output is

```
a: 0
b: 0
c: 1
d: -1
e: 0
```

Comment: hello sir. The professor said that for this exercise, the numbers are different. so i don't have to check this.

Comment: @IliaNaleva Nevertheless it will be correct to check this. Otherwise who should check this?:) Without such a check the function is wrong.

Comment: @IliaNaleva For example what to do with an array that has only one element  as { 1 }?

Comment: i've added a check so size will be size>2.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about you try this( although it is long )
you keep the data of the original array to another temporary array like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
  //assuming arr is your array and size is the no. of data//

  arr[i]=temp[i]; //here we store each data of the original to a temporary
}
```

and then ascend the temp array:

```
//Selection sorting the temp array in ascending

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++ )
  {
    if(temp[i]<temp[j])
     {
        swap = temp[i];
        temp[i] = temp[j];
        temp[j] = swap;
     }
  }
}
```

then compare your original array and the ascended temp array, if they are equal, the original array is ascending, if not move to doing the same way with descending(i.e. descend the temp array then then again compare, if they are equal ur original array is descending )

if neither, your array is random

Comment: That's a rather expensive way to do things.

Comment: Yes..it indeed is...but hey as long it works

Answer (score -1):

```
        int UpOrDown(int *arr,int size)
{
int i = 0 ; //try to intialize the elements its good habbit also put spaces like i had done .its just good coding guidance 
int j = 0 ;
int flag = 0;

if ( arr[0] < arr[1] )// ascending or random
{
        for(i = 1 ; i < size ;i++)
           {
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
                flag = 1;
             else
    {
                flag = 0 ;
        break ;
    }

            }
}

else //descending or random
{

            for(i=1;i< size;i++)
                {
                  if(arr[i]<arr[i+1])
                    flag = -1;
        else
        {
                    flag = 0 ;
        break ;
        }
            }
  }
return flag;
}
```

i am considering there is no repeated elements in your code

Comment: do you know if this function running O(n-1)?